# Fetch CPU current speed

Tags: android

I'm supposed to calculate the battery consumption of each and every application. For this i'm considering fetching CPU details as the first step. I've got the CPU usage per application. Now I think i might need the current CPU frequency per application. I tried using the following code:

"/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"

Its giving me the maximum frequency of the CPU at anytime.
Is there any possibility of fetching this information programatically?? Please help some one.

Answer (score 0):

CPU isn't the big battery used on a mobile phone.  Display and radio are.  GPS usage, data usage, and how long the user has the phone on with that app in the foreground are much better proxies for battery than CPU usage, the CPU is almost free.  To prove it-  put a phone in airplane mode, keep the screen off, and see how long it runs.  It will last for days.

Comment: Yes you are right but according to the reference of power tutor application, CPU usage consideration is a must.As i've looked into this concept, based on the current battery status a GOVERNOR will be adopted which inturn handles the CPU speed. If the current battery status is high then performance GOVERNOR will be adopted which drain more battery life. If what i've looked into is right then i cant neglect considering CPU info.

Answer (score 0):

just check this out :I've observed that sometimes the order in which the frequencies is listed can vary, so you'll want to iterate through the whole list and find the fastest (as opposed to stopping at the first non-zero).

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19810/how-can-i-determine-max-cpu-speed-at-runtime

Comment: Thank you very much. Will execute it and will let you know.

Comment: In HTC Explorer A310e its getting executed successfully, but in Samsung GT S530 it is throwing FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION on this line:   RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile( "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state", "r" );

Comment: i'm not getting why this refused to run on Samsung GT S530.. actually i never tried this on that device ... i'll check this out ...

Comment: use this " /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies " may be it helps you ....

Comment: ok ..... hey do u have rooted Samsung GT S530..if your device is rooted you can find cpu folder manually and than give the required path in your code..

Comment: No i dont have rooted samsung device. I need this for BatteryConsumption calculation.

Comment: so its hard to find the path of cpufreq files ... :(

Comment: just try these : #cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"
#cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq"
#cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq"